# JavaScript: Why does checkLeaf need parameter when scope already allows access?

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, parameter-passing, binary-tree

Our instructor wrote this function that recursively searches a JavaScript object.

My question concerns the scope of the `leaf` and `value` parameters passed into the outer `isContained` function: Per my understanding of variable scope, the inner `checkLeaf` function already has access to the variables being passed into the outer function. This is self evident upon observing both the `leaf` and `value` variables being accessed inside the `checkLeaf` function.

So why the need to pass in `leaf` to `checkLeaf`? Furthermore, if parameters are to be passed, then why only `leaf` and not `value` as well, since both are obviously being accessed from within the inner function?

```
const isContained = function(leaf, value) {
  function checkLeaf(leaf) {

    if (leaf.value === value) {
      return true;
    }
    if (leaf.left && leaf.value > value) {
      return checkLeaf(leaf.left);
    }
    if (leaf.right) return checkLeaf(leaf.right);
    return checkLeaf(leaf);
  }
}

isContained(binarySearchTree, 6);
```

Comment: Because leaf changes-it's not always the value passed to the outer function.

Comment: Okay, so this has to do with recursion?

Comment: Ah, the value of leaf changes as it searches the binary tree, but the value searched for (value) doesn't.

Comment: Run it-debug it. Play computer with pencil and paper.

Comment: Correct-the value you're searching for doesn't change, so the original enclosed value doesn't need to be passed along. It *could* be, and if `checkLeaf` function did on its own it would need to be (like if you wanted to be able to test it separately).

Comment: You just helped me understand this better; this question would be useful to a lot of people out there. Maybe you could post an answer so I can accept it and possibly improve its ranking?

Comment: @Sean -- yes, this is highly useful for others.  However, the issue has been handled many times on Stack Overflow.  I don't know that another instance of explanation will improve the archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leaf` is the only variable passed into the inner function `checkLeaf` because it is the only variable that will change while `checkLeaf` goes through its recursive call stack. The variable `value` remains unchanged as it is what is being searched for, therefore it doesn't need to also be passed into the `checkLeaf` function.

Comment: Without formatting, "*the variable value remains unchanged*" might be misunderstood as "the value of the variable `leaf`".